# how to use Devops Pipelines and Releases: Deploying One solution with 6 webjob console app as one zip file/package

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

**My situation :** I have 1 solution with 6 console apps.

**My target :** publish 6 console apps as 6 web jobs under 1 App service.

**Summary :**

6 consoleapps -->convert --> 6 dlls in 1 ZIP file --> Publish --> 6 webjobs in 1 App Service

How can I do that in Yaml?

azure-pipeline.yaml :

```js
trigger:
  - main

variables:         
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: 'Build stage'
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildOrderShipmentJob
    displayName: 'Build Order Shipment Job'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      displayName: 'checkout'
    
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
      displayName: "NuGet use 6.3.0"
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 6.3.0

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'nuget restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        feedsToUse: 'select'

    - task: MSBuild@1
      displayName: 'msbuild'
      inputs:
        solution: 'src/xxxxx/xxxxx.csproj'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/xxxxx-$(Build.BuildNumber)/App_Data/jobs/continuous/xxxxx'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'package'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/xxxxx-$(Build.BuildNumber)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/xxxxx-$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true
      
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'publish'
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/xxxxx-$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'

- stage: Test
  displayName: 'Test stage'
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  jobs:
  - job: TestOrderShipmentJob
    displayName: 'Test Order Shipment Job'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      displayName: 'checkout'
    
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
      displayName: "NuGet use 6.3.0"
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 6.3.0
        
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'nuget restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'vsbuild'
      inputs:
        solution: '**/*.sln'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        clean: true

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'dotnet test'
      inputs:
        command: test
        arguments: '--collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura'
        publishTestResults: true
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src' 

    - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
      displayName: 'publish code coverage results'
      inputs:
        codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
        summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'

- stage: Deploy_Test
  displayName: 'Deploy test'
  dependsOn: Test
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  pool:
    name: 'bmersgtsteuw-app-eurotracs-pool'
  jobs:
  - deployment: BaukingOrderShipmentJob
    displayName: 'Deploy Order Shipment Job'
    environment: 'BME-CF-Test'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: drop
            - task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: AzureRM
                azureSubscription: 'ARM-Con-BME-SUB-TST-EUW-APP'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'xxxapptsteuw-app-tst'
                package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/xxxxx-$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
                removeAdditionalFilesFlag: true

- stage: Deploy_Prod
  displayName: 'Deploy production'
  dependsOn: Deploy_Test
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  pool:
    name: 'xxxrsgprdeuw-app-tst-pool'
  jobs:
  - deployment: YYYYYOrderShipmentJob
    displayName: 'Deploy Order Shipment Job'
    environment: XXXX-CF-Prod
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: current
              artifact: drop
            - task: AzureRMWebAppDeployment@4
              inputs:
                ConnectionType: AzureRM
                azureSubscription: 'ARM-Con-XXXX-SUB-PRD-EUW-APP'
                appType: 'webApp'
                WebAppName: 'xxxappprdeuw-app-tst'
                package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/xxxxx-$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
                removeAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

Comment: Can you specify which step exactly is not working for you? Which part of the yaml is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your situation, you have 1 solution with 6 console apps.

> 6 consoleapps -->convert --> 6 dlls in 1 ZIP file --> Publish --> 6 webjobs in 1 App Service

To achieve your requirement, you can directly define the solution file and modify the `msbuildArguments` in Msbuild task.

For example:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **/*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
```

Then the  6 console apps in 1 solution file will be built and the output will be saved at one zip file. So you can remove the ArchiveFiles task in YAML sample

Comment: What if I ask my question like that :  1 ZIP --> AppData/jobs/continuous/WebApp1 (webApp1.exe,dll),  WebApp2 (webApp2.exe, dll etc.) .I am separating different directories